# Display API data using Axios and a list in React

Tags: json, reactjs, rendering, axios

I'm attempting to make a request to this https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api API in a React project and then display JSON data on my site.

I'm using Axios to make the request and I have been able to make the request and get the appropriate JSON data and console.log it or view it in the React tools in Firefox. However, I am having difficulty displaying the data in a ul. Initially I had an error pertaining to having a unique key for each list item, and I have since resolved that (or so I believe).

Here's my request and how I am attempting to render the data:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from "axios";


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=*apikeyhere*&language=en-US&page=1`)
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data.results.map(obj => [obj.title, obj.overview]);
        this.setState({ posts });
      });
  }

/*  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Movie API data</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map(post =>
              <li key={post.toString()}>{post.title}</li>
            )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
*/

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.posts.map(function(post, index){
          return (
              <div key={index}>
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                <p>{post.overview}</p>
              </div>
            )
          }
        )}
      </ul>
    );

  }

}
```

As you can see I attempted multile approaches to rendering this. What's wrong with my code and why isn't the JSON data rendering in the ul on my site?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you setup a jsFiddle or codepen that recreates the problem? Just from looking at your code, it looks like the only way it won't render is if there isn't any data in `this.state.posts`.

Comment: Oh wait, this isn't the full app right? You need to have `ReactDOM.render( <App/>, document.getElementById('root'));` somewhere that will actually render your react app.

Comment: If you add `console.log(posts)` before you `setState`, what is the output? Do you see an array of data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you have an error inside success fuction `({title: obj.title, overview: obj.overview})`

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=*apikeyhere*&language=en-US&page=1`)
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data.results.map(obj => ({title: obj.title, overview: obj.overview}));
        this.setState({ posts });
      });
  }
```

Comment: That did the trick. Looks like the whole problem was me using an array there instead of an object with key/value pairs. Thanks.